# Razor page without any controller is not rendering the _layout.cshtml file

Tags: razor

I have a simple project containing just few razor pages.
It was working fine and all of a sudden, the default page which is in cshtml file was not rendering the layout from `~/_layout.cshtml`.

All the cshtml, css and _layout.cshtml files are in the same location i.e. root location.

So please somebody help on this.